# Bash script not returning output

Tags: bash, xquartz

I am practicing writing simple bash scripts. I wrote the following script in TextEdit and saved it as a .sh file.

```
for x in “$@“
do
    if x = 0; 
        then
            echo “False”
    elif x = 1; 
        then
            echo “True”
    fi
done
```

When I call this script in XQuartz using the following syntax, it runs forever and does not output anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
sh TestBash.sh 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: `if x = 0` will attempt to execute the command `x = 0` and will enter the first branch if that command succeeds.  Is there a command `x` in your PATH?

Comment: Note that `“` is not `"`. Only the latter is a valid double quote symbol.

Comment: [Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting mistakes like these -- I recommend running your scripts through it and fixing what it points out.

Comment: Adding to WilliamPursell's comment: In Linux, the command `x` would normally start the X server, and then waits forever, until it is shut down. I would have however expected that it writes at least some startup messages to stdout. Maybe you have another `x` in your PATH; you can verify this by entering `type x` on the command line. BTW, if you want to test the variable `x` numerically, the command would be `if (( x==0 ))`. If you want to test it as string, it is `if [[ $x == 0 ]]`.

Comment: Given error msg you have added below AND your use of `“` and `”` for quoting characters, (you should use plain dbl-quotes, i.e. `"`), I think you need to find the correct formatting mode for your editor. Use `vim` and you won't have to worry about such issues. `++` that you mentioned (I just noticed) that you are using `TextEdit` .Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

To compare the x variable to an integer:

```
((x == 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing the syntax to ```if ((x==0))``` at least gave me an error instead of running forever. Any idea what this error message means?

TestBash.sh: line 6: ((: â0â: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "â0â")

Comment: It tells you `x` has extra characters, not just the number `0`, so it isn't a valid number. In this case that's because your code was written with "smart quotes", not real ASCII quotes.

Comment: Note that `((x == 0))` will try to interpret the value of the variable `x` as an integer; if it's something else, you may get weird results. `[ "$x" = 0 ]` or `[[ "$x" = 0 ]]` will compare it as a string instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in "$@"
do
    if ((x == 0)); 
        then
            echo "False"
    elif ((x == 1)); 
        then
            echo "True"
    fi
done
```